# How to use a method inside service in a child component in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

In backend API some data is there. From front-end, i generate to get a request to read those backend data and show in front-end. For this, i created an Offer component and two child components of this offer component i.e general & special component. I created one service, within that i created one method, inside the method i generate to get a request to connect with backend API. Now when i am trying to import this service to that child component i am getting compilation to fail error in visual studio code saying "ERROR in `app/offers/general/general.component.ts:2:30` - error

> TS2307: Cannot find module '../event.service'

. Now my question "how to use a service by a child component in the angular application"? 
in general.component.ts ->

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-general',

  templateUrl: './general.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general.component.css']
})
export class GeneralComponent implements OnInit {
  events = [];
  constructor(private _eventservice: EventService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._eventservice.showGeneralOffers().subscribe(
      res => this.events = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

}
```

in event.service.ts ->

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {
  private _generalOffersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/general';
  private _specialOffersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/special';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getGeneralOffers() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._generalOffersUrl);
  }
  getSpecialOffers() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._specialOffersUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: is your service and component are at same folder level?

Comment: Yes, in same folder.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like issue with the importing service path. (import { EventService } from '../event.service';). Check given path is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a simple path problem.
Delete import of service in generalComponent costructor, go over EventService, a popup will come out, and click on quick fix, automatically will write the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Your relative path to import is wrong, change it to,

```js
import { EventService } from './event.service';
```